# ValueError: Shapes (None, 7) and (None, 8) are incompatible

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I keep on getting the same error I think I have the problem with the input shapes, Please help me

```
X = Features.iloc[: ,:-1].values
Y = Features['labels'].values
```

As this is a multiclass classification problem onehotencoding our Y.

```
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
Y = encoder.fit_transform(np.array(Y).reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

# splitting data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape

# scaling our data with sklearn's Standard scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape

# making our data compatible to model.
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=2)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=2)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape, x_train.shape[1]
```

The model

```
 model=Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(units=8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

rlrp = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.4, verbose=0, patience=2, min_lr=0.0000001)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[rlrp])
#history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks=[rlrp])
```

I'm getting the error when trying to fit the model.

Comment: post the code, not a screenshot of the code

Comment: I have posted the code intead of a snapshot as per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code running.
Since you did not provide any sample data, I had to fake some data and I will explain what is the issue.
Your y_train must have a depth of 8 since your softmax layer is 8.
If you want to get the same error in my code, change

```
y_train = tf.one_hot(tf.random.uniform(shape=[1000],minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32),8)  #change the depth to 7 and you will see your error
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_train = tf.random.normal(shape=(1000,10,1), dtype = tf.float32)
x_test = tf.random.normal(shape=(100,10,1), dtype = tf.float32)
y_train = tf.one_hot(tf.random.uniform(shape=[1000],minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32),8)
y_test = tf.one_hot(tf.random.uniform(shape=[100],minval=0, maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32),8)
tf.print(y_train)


model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(256, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=5, strides = 2, padding = 'same'))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))

model.add(layers.Dense(units=8, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = 'categorical_crossentropy' , metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()

rlrp = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.4, verbose=0, patience=2, min_lr=0.0000001)
reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[rlrp])
#history=model.fit(x_train, y_train, callbacks=[rlrp])

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
Y = encoder.fit_transform(np.array(Y).reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

# splitting data
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape

# scaling our data with sklearn's Standard scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape

# making our data compatible to model.
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=2)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=2)
x_train.shape, y_train.shape, x_test.shape, y_test.shape, x_train.shape[1]
```

Comment: print the shape of your y_train and you will see